# ionic devapp - module card.io does not exist

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

my Ionic Devapp randomly stopped working properly. Not sure what I did to cause this.

When I serve my app and open it on the dev app, it opens per norm and everything works. If I close it and reboot it, I get the error

"Module card.io.cordova.mobilesdk.CardIO does not exist."
When I tap "Close", it just gives me a white screen.

Note: I do not use Card.IO in my project, however at some point in the far past I did install Card.io on this project but then removed it. It's been working fine ever since up until now.

I tried adding Card.IO back to the project with:
ionic cordova plugin add card.io.cordova.mobilesdk
npm install @ionic-native/card-io

To see if that would make it happy, but it's still throwing the same error message.

Just wondering if anyone else ever ran into this/has any insight on how to fix this?

[image: image of error message]